# Do I need different certificates for every thing?

Tags: networking, security, aws-iot, aws

I'm learning AWS and I created a new `thing` with the required certificates to access it via MQTT:

- root-CA.crt
- .private.key
- .cert.pem

If I'm not wrong the `root-CA.crt` file will be the same for all the `things` because it's used to authenticate the server.

What I don't understand if I need to create a **different** set of certificates (private.key and cert.pem) for **every** device I will build.

Comment: This is exactly the question I have been looking for. I the answer of @hardillb is good, but I would arguable say that it is a very very short answer. There is more things to be said about that, I will keep thinking about that and let you know if I anything useful comes to my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the whole point of using client side certificates is to enable you to reliably uniquely identify each client.

AWS will provide APIs to provision each device with it's own cert/key.

The other reason is that it means that you can easily ban a single device if the certificate is compromised, if every device reuses the same certificate then you have to recall all the devices and update them if somebody gets hold of the key/cert pair.